# My program doesnt print the result of a function for my last line of code

Tags: c, comparison, variable-declaration

This code take input from the user (characters C,T,B) and (int 0-24 and 0-60) to calculate the cost of parking based on the type of vehicle the user inputs.

the last line of code in the program is supossed to print the result of the function "charged" which is determined by the type of vehicle declared by the user inputed char value but when i run it only retruns 0.00 instead of the flaot value any and all help is appreciated :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>



int total_minute_parked (int minute_in, int minute_left)
{
    int minute_parked;
    if (minute_in > minute_left)
    {
        minute_parked = (minute_left  - minute_in + 60);
    }
    else
    {
        minute_parked = (minute_left - minute_in);
    }
    return minute_parked;
}

// func calc total hours parked

int total_hour_parked (int hour_in, int hour_left)
{
    int hours_parked;
    if (hour_left > hour_in)
    {

        hours_parked = abs((hour_left - 1) - hour_in);
    }
    else
    {
        hours_parked = abs(hour_left - hour_in);
    }

    return hours_parked ;
}

// -------------------funtion to calc charge based off type of vehicle------

float charged (char vehicle_type,int total_hour_parked)
{

    char C;
    char T;
    char B;

    float temp_charged;

    if  (vehicle_type == C) // -------------------------------CAR
    {
        if (total_hour_parked > 3)
        {
            float secondary_hour = total_hour_parked - 3;
            temp_charged = secondary_hour * 1.5;
        }
        else
        {
            temp_charged = 0;
        }
    }

    else if  (vehicle_type == T)   // ------------------------------TRUCK
    {
        if (total_hour_parked > 2)
        {
            float secondary_hour = total_hour_parked - 2;
            temp_charged = (secondary_hour * 2.3) + 1.0;
        }
        else {
            temp_charged = 1;
        }
    }

    else if  (vehicle_type == B) // -----------------------------------BUS
    {
        if (total_hour_parked > 1)
        {
            float secondary_hour = total_hour_parked - 1;
            temp_charged = (secondary_hour * 3.7) + 2.0;
        }
        else {
            temp_charged = 2;
        }
    }
    return temp_charged;
}

//---------------------- end program upon invalid imput -------------------//



// --------------------- main that prints results and takes imput -----------//

int main()

{

    int total_hour_parked (int hour_in,int hour_left);
    float charged (char vehicle_type, int total_hour_parked);
    char vehicle_type;
    int hour_in = 0;
    int minute_in = 0;

    int hour_left = 0;
    int minute_left = 0;

    printf("Please enter the type of Vehicle:");
    scanf("%c",&vehicle_type);

    printf("Please enter the hour entered lot:");
    scanf("%d", &hour_in);

    printf("Please enter the minute entered lot:");
    scanf("%d", &minute_in);

    printf("Please enter the hour left lot:");
    scanf("%d", &hour_left);

    printf("Please enter the minute left lot:");
    scanf("%d", &minute_left);

    printf("------------------------------------\n");

    printf("Parking time: %d:%d\n", total_hour_parked(hour_in,hour_left),total_minute_parked(minute_in,minute_left));

    printf("Cost %f",charged(vehicle_type,total_hour_parked));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you really mean to have `vehicle_type  == 'C'`? Because `vehicle_type == C` makes no sense as the variable `C` is uninitialized and will have an indeterminate (and seemingly random) value.

Comment: Fyi, there are *many* warnings in this code, in particular related to usage of *indeterminate* variables in expressions.  Things like `if  (vehicle_type == C)` make no sense, when the **variable** `C` has no determinate value. I concur with Some programmer dude. It *looks* like you want to use character literals in this. The final printf arguments don't make much sense either. `int total_hour_parked (int hour_in,int hour_left);` declares a *function*. Passing it as an argument (uncalled, so a function *pointer*) to `charged` makes no sense.

Comment: you already ask about another problem in this code, maybe its time to use debugger?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's going to solve all the problems in the code, but there's an issue here:

```
char C;
char T;
char B;

float temp_charged;

if  (vehicle_type == C) // -------------------------------CAR
```

What this does is it declares three `char` and doesn't assign any value (so accessing them is undefined and will result in some rubbish value). Then you are comparing `vehicle_type` against those chars. The result will most likely be `false` (or `0`). That's not what you intended. Instead, do this:

```
if  (vehicle_type == 'C')
```

You probably misunderstood what `char C;` means. It doesn't mean "make a `char` with value `'C'`", but "make a `char` named `C` and don't initialize it". But in this scenario you don't need those three chars anyway bcause you can just compare `vehicle_type` with a literal.

Answer (score 0):

Their are several problems in the above code.

**1).** You are comparing `vehicle_type` with the `char` which are not `assign` so first assign the values to this `char` variables

```
char C = 'C';
char T = 'T';
char B = 'B';
```

Or you can directly compare like

```
if (vehicle_type == 'T')
```

**2).** `total_hour_parked` is a function not a `integer` variable so what you can do is store the `return value` of `total_hour_parked` in any variable

Eg:-

```
int m_total_hour_parked = total_hour_parked(hour_in, hour_left);
printf("Parking time: %d:%d\n", m_total_hour_parked, total_minute_parked(minute_in, minute_left));
printf("Cost %f", charged(vehicle_type, m_total_hour_parked));
```

Hopefully that helps